# How to add a pedestrian button code to a traffic light with ultrasonic sensor?

Tags: programming, button

So I have a project to create a 2 set of traffic lights which would detect a car coming and stopping on the ultrasonic sensor and my code would allow the traffic lights to loop and let the car through. But now I also have to add a pedestrian code in for the pedestrians to press the button, the traffic lights to loop back to red and give 30 seconds of crossing time.

I did the ultrasonic sensor traffic lights code already and some of it seems confusing but somehow works quite well. I'm not familiar with the buttons and looping the traffic lights correctly back to red so I need help to add a pedestrian crossing code to this code:

```
// Variables for Station 1 Traffic Light Components
const int Red1LED = 9;
const int Yellow1LED = 2;
const int Green1LED = 3;
const int GreenArrow = 4;
#define trigPin 12 
#define echoPin 13
// Setup Variables for Station 2 Traffic Light Components
const int Red2LED = 5;
const int Yellow2LED = 6;
const int Green2LED = 7;
const int GreenArrow2 = 8;

void setup() {

  pinMode(Red1LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Yellow1LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Green1LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GreenArrow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Red2LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Yellow2LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Green2LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GreenArrow2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);
  // Set Initial state of all red LED to HIGH
  digitalWrite (Red1LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (Red2LED, HIGH);
}




void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  // Added this line
  delayMicroseconds(2); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
//  delayMicroseconds(1000); - Removed this line
  //delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  //digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
  Serial.println(distance);
  if (distance < 20) {  // This is where the LED On/Off happens
     delay(1000);  //  1 Seconds of Red
  digitalWrite(Green1LED, LOW);  //  Sets Red1 OFF Green ON
  digitalWrite(Yellow1LED, HIGH);
  delay(1000);  // 1 Seconds of Green
  digitalWrite(Yellow1LED, LOW);  //  Sets Green1 OFF Yellow ON
  digitalWrite(Red1LED, HIGH);
  delay(1000);  // 1 Seconds of Yellow
   // Station 2 Timing
  delay(1000);  //  1 Second of Red
  digitalWrite(Red2LED, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(GreenArrow2, HIGH);  //  Sets Red2 OFF Green ON
  delay(1000);  // 1 Second of Green
  digitalWrite(GreenArrow2, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(Green2LED, HIGH);  //  Sets Green ARROW OFF Yellow ON
  delay(1000);  // 1 Second of Yellow
  digitalWrite(Green2LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Yellow2LED, HIGH); // Sets Green 2 OFF YELLOW OFF
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(Yellow2LED, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(Red2LED, HIGH);

   digitalWrite(Red1LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GreenArrow, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(GreenArrow, LOW);  //  Sets Yellow1 OFF Red ON
  digitalWrite( Green1LED, HIGH);
}
  else {
   digitalWrite(Red1LED, LOW); // When the Red condition is met, the Green LED should turn off
  digitalWrite(Red2LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(GreenArrow, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Green1LED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Yellow1LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Yellow2LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Green2LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GreenArrow2, LOW);

  }
}
```

I NEED HELP ASAP PLEASE. Due tomorrow by 12 am. It is extension so I am not that worried if I don't get help by the deadline but if I still do after the deadline I can still learn so don't hesitate to post.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for making it clear that this is course work.
You are asking for help to do the extension, but by your own words you don't understand how the core code works.  I have to be honest I can't be bothered to read the code, it looks horrible.  If I was your teacher I would quit, because I have failed to teach you one of the most fundamental aspects of coding.  "You write it once but it gets read many times", it is ALWAYS worth spending a few minutes making the code look pretty!  (If you teacher can't be bothered to read it, you aren't going to get 100%!)

1. Comments - commenting out code is not the best use for // explaining **why** you are doing what you are doing is.
2. Its good that you have defined variables to identify you pins, but you have two identical sets of variables, so you could have used an array, a structure or an array of structures.  (These might be more advanced than where you are at the moment, sorry if that's the case).
3. Breaking you code down into bite sized pieces make it more readable.  That start of your loop contains some code that could be in a function called `getDistance()`
4. Turning the lights on and off in the way you are doing it is open to errors.  You could turn the red light on and the green light on.  If you made a class to represent the lights then you could have a function that turned off all of the lights and only turned on the one you wanted.  You wouldn't need to store the state.

Example code (not tested or compiled)

```
class Lights
{
  public:
    enum eLight {Red, Amber, Green, GreenArrow, GreenPedestrian, RedPedestrian, eMaxLight};
    Lights(int[] pins)
    {
      for (int l = 0; l < eMaxLight; ++l)
        pinMode (pins[l], OUTPUT);     
    }
    ~Lights()
    {}
    void setLight (eLight newLight)
    {
       for (int l = 0; l < eMaxLight; ++l)
         digitalWrite(m_Light[l], LOW);
       digitalWrite(m_Light[newLight], HIGH);
    }
}
```

You probably want to look at a state machine.  List all the possible LEGAL combinations and then create a enum with each of those states in and then write a function that moves from a state to the next legal state, you will need conditionals for has the button been pressed.  This should give you a working system with a pedestrian button that hopefully you understand.

Comment: Thanks for answering but the code you have given me includes pedestrian lights. I would rather just press the button and have all the lights turn off. How does the code work and what does each line do because I'm very confused. And what is a enum? My code was rather simple because it is all we know. We just started learning arduino and our teacher has been away for quite awhile now. And compared to other students in my class this was the shortest code so I guess you can't expect better for beginners. I just have to learn coding all together to be honest.

Comment: An enum is a way of representing a discrete set of values with words in your code.  (A better description is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e.aspx).  So a pedestrian presses the button on pin 'x' and the traffic lights go off?  or do you mean the lights go red.  That should be "easy" to achieve.  Delete the pedestrian values from the enum.  Attach a button and get it to trigger an interrupt (see Arduino website).  The interrupt handler will set the value of a `volatile bool` to true.  Your main code will have to check this value regularly, and change the lights.